# AWK: Add number to the column for specific line

Tags: bash, awk

I have a data file of:

```
1  2  3
1  5  7
2  5  9
11 21 110
6  17 -2
10 2  8
6  4  3
5  1  8
6  1  5
7  3  1
```

I want to add number 1 to the third column, only for line number 1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 10. And add 2 to the second column, for line number 6~9.

I know how to add 2 to entire second column, and add 1 to entire third column using awk

```
awk '{print $1, $2+2, $3+1}' data > data2
```

But how can I modify this code to specific lines of second and third column?

Thanks

Best,

Comment: AWK has the $NR variabele for rhis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue! You can check for NR in the condition, but for 6 values it will be tedious, alternatively you can check for string match with  anchored NR.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{lines=",1,3,6,8,9,10,"}
       match(lines,","NR","){$3++}
   NR>=6 && NR<=9{$2+=2}1' nums  

1 2 4
1  5  7
2 5 10
11 21 110
6  17 -2
10 4 9
6 6 3
5 3 9
6 3 6
7 3 2
```

Comment: Alternatively, `BEGIN {a[1];a[3];a[6];a[8];a[9];a[10]}; NR in a {$3++}`;

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    for (i=6;i<=9;i++) {
        d[2,i] = 2
    }

    split("1 3 6 8 9 10",t);
    for (i in t) {
        d[3,t[i]] = 1
    }
}
{ $2 += d[2,NR]; $3 += d[3,NR]; print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
1 2 4
1 5 7
2 5 10
11 21 110
6 17 -2
10 4 9
6 6 3
5 3 9
6 3 6
7 3 2
```